# Using rolify with existing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a role model all ready in my application.

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :department
end
```

How can I use https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify given that I wont be able to generate and run the migration file ?

Comment: You wanted to integrated the gem to your existing model, right?

Comment: Yes that's right.